# C++, почему для && ссылки вызывается перегрузка const &

Tags: c++, rvalue

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
class Object
{
    public:
    // ...
    private:
    list<unique_ptr<Element>> elements;
};

void Object::add(unique_ptr<Element> &&_element)
{
    elements.push_back(_element);
}
```

При сборке этого кода в `Visual Studio 2019` для `push_back()` вызывается перегрузка:

```
push_back(const unique_ptr<Element> &_element);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это какой-то баг?

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Где вы видите баг и где вы видите "конвертацию `rvalue` в `lvalue`"* Поясните вопрос. В языке С++ любая именованная ссылка является lvalue.

Comment: @AnT, мне надо подумать, потому что я окончательно запутался. Я считал, что ссылка `&&` - это ссылка, предназначенная для перемещения.

Comment: В языке С++ любая именованная ссылка является lvalue. И `&`, и `&&`.

Comment: @AnT, тогда какая разница, что именно я передаю в параметр, `&` или `&&`? Два этих варианта были введены, чтобы можно было выполнить перегрузку по типу параметра, например, для операторов копирования/перемещения?

Comment: Разница большая: если, например, вы передадите временный объект, то вариант c `&` будет неприменим.

Comment: @AnT, почему неприменим?

Comment: Ко временному объекту можно привязать только `const &` ссылку. Неконстантная `&` ссылка ко временному объекту не привяжется.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Видимо вас вводит в заблуждения терминолигия С++. Дело в том, что термин rvalue может использоваться для обозначения двух разных, независимых понятий:

- тип rvalue reference, тип переменной `_element`, объявленной как `unique_ptr<Element> &&_element` в вашем примере
- категория выражения rvalue, результат `std::move(_element)` (xvalue) или `unique_ptr<Element>{}` (prvalue) в вашем примере

Так вот, чтобы выражение подходило под тип rvalue reference оно должно иметь категорию rvalue, а не тип rvalue reference. А у вас `_element` имеет тип rvalue reference но относится к категории lvalue.

Comment: Позанудствую немного: *Переменная* `_element` имеет тип `unique_ptr<Element> &&`. *Выражение* `_element` - тип `unique_ptr<Element>` (потому что выражения [не могут](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1) иметь ссылочные типы).

Answer (score 5):

Термин rvalue в языке С++ обозначает либо prvalue, либо xvalue. prvalue - это либо выражение-инициализатор в объявлении, либо выражение-операнд оператора. xvalue - это в большинстве случаев либо временный объект, либо неименованная rvalue-ссылка  (плюс несколько дополнительных контекстов, в которых невременный объект может выступать в качестве xvalue).

Ни один из этих случаев не относится к вашему примеру. То есть никакого rvalue в вашем примере нет.

Rvalue-ссылка может выступать в качестве xvalue, но только тогда, когда она *не именована*. Именованная rvalue-ссылка является lvalue. В вашем случае выражение `_element` является lvalue.

В том числе для того, что превращать именованные rvalue-ссылки в неименованные существует `std::move`.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы rvalue-ссылку можно было инициализировать каким-то выражением, это выражение должно иметь категорию ([value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value%20category)) rvalue.

(То есть если параметр функции - это rvalue-ссылка, то в качестве аргумента можно передать только выражение с категорией rvalue.)

Но если использовать имя rvalue-ссылки (да и вообще любой переменной) как выражение, категория такого выражения - lvalue. (Такая вот причуда языка.)

То есть хотя переменная `unique_ptr<Element> &&_element` имеет тип "rvalue-ссылка на `unique_ptr<Element>`", категория выражения `_element` - это lvalue.

Используйте `elements.push_back(std::move(_element));`.

Comment: Я пять часов разбирался в тонне ошибок, которые были вызваны вот таким неожиданным поведением... И все ошибки указывали куда угодно, только не туда, куда нужно!