# Использование std::move() при инициализации членов в конструкторе

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, move, перемещение

Допустим, имеем типичный класс:

```
class worker
{
  std::string name;
  std::string lastname;
  std::string dob;
public:
  worker(std::string &&n, std::string &&l, std::string &&d)
    : name(n), lastname(l), dob(d)
  {  }
  ~worker() = default;
};
```

Какой вариант конструктора лучше использовать, такой, или с std::move()?

```
worker(std::string &&n, std::string &&l, std::string &&d)
        : name(std::move(n)),
          lastname(std::move(l)),
          dob(std::move(d))
{  }
```

Comment: Вариант без `move` бесполезен, ведь ничего же не перемещается.

Comment: Но, так ведь move() приводит переменную к r-value, ничего не перемещая. Фактически перемещение происходит в конструкторе std::string(string&&)

Comment: Как раз за счет приведения к r-value и будет вызываться перемещающий конструктор для std::string, а без него - вызовется копирующий.

Comment: Да. Но у нас изначально string &&, зачем ее еще раз приводить к string &&

Comment: Без `move` ваши параметры, как имеющие имя и адрес, будут трактоваться как lvalue. Словом, `move` нужен.

Comment: вам стоит ознакомиться с [C++, почему для && ссылки вызывается перегрузка const &](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014008/c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-const/1014009#1014009) ну или это вопрос-дубликат получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [живой пример](https://ideone.com/t8Mka2) -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test()             { cout << "Test()\n"; }
    Test(int x):val_(x){ cout << "Test(" << x << ")\n"; }
    Test(const Test& t):val_(t.val_) { cout << "Test(const Test& " << t.val_ << ")\n"; }
    Test(Test&&t)      :val_(t.val_) { cout << "Test(const Test&& " << t.val_ << ")\n"; t.val_ = 0; }
    ~Test()           { cout << "~Test(" << val_ <<")\n"; }
private:
    int val_ = 0;
};

struct Quest
{
    Test t;
    Quest(Test&& t):t(t){}
};

struct Qwest
{
    Test t;
    Qwest(Test&& t):t(move(t)){}
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test t(5), s(6);
    Quest q(move(t));
    Qwest w(move(s));
}
```

Убедились в необходимости `move`?

Comment: Т.е. std::move() нужно использовать и в таком случае: vector<mystruct> vi; vi.emplace_back(mystruct());

Comment: @KoD Здесь не нужно, потому что `mystruct()` - уже rvalue. Можно написать проще: `vi.emplace_back();`.

Comment: @KoD В дубликате этот вопрос же освещается.

Answer (score 0):

Ни тот ни другой. В оба конструктора нельзя передавать lvalue.

Например, если у вас есть `std::string name = "Bob";`, то при *вызове* конструктора вам придется писать `std::move(name)` - очень неудобно!

Вот такой конструктор больше подходит:

```
worker(std::string n, std::string l, std::string d)
        : name(std::move(n)),
          lastname(std::move(l)),
          dob(std::move(d))
```

А если параметров мало (1-2), то в качестве оптимизации можно сделать 2<sup>n</sup> конструкторов с параметрами `const std::string &` и `std::string &&` (во втором случае нужен `std::move`, как написано в соседнем ответе). Тогда для каждой переменной у вас будет на одно перемещение меньше.

Comment: "Вот такой конструктор больше подходит"  чтобы наплодить временных объектов

Comment: @user7860670 Нуу. С другой стороны, использовать везде rvalue-ссылки и на каждый чих ставить `move` (то есть при вызове таких конструкторов с lvalue) для меня выглядит как преждевременная оптимизация.